# Scroll inner div (having vertical scroll) horizontally with outer div using CSS

Tags: css

I need Outer div with horizontal scroll and inner div with vertical scroll and inner div should move with outer div.

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="outer">content outer
        <div id="inner"> 
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>column1</td>                
              <td>column2</td> 
              <td>column2</td>  
              <td>column2</td>  
              <td>column2</td>                      
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

```
#wrapper {
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}

#outer {
    background-color: red;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#inner {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height:150px;
    background-color: blue; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    position:relative; z-index:1;
}
```

When I apply overflow-y: scroll; to Inner Div, horizontal scroll comes with Inner div and not the outer div.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Can you please clear?

Comment: To achieve that, you need your outer div to be overflowed in X axis. This is not happening with the code your provided. Your inner DIV should be bigger than the outer div, or there should be more elements inside the outer div that overflow it horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will work for you

$("#outer").scroll(function() {

```
$("#inner").scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
```

});

:) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand well what you actually want.

```
#wrapper{
Width:200px;
height:300px;
overflow:hidden;
}

#outer{
width:400px;
height:300px;
Overflow:auto;
}
#inner{
width:200px;
Height:500px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: I have two Divs one outer div in which I need horizontal scroll and it should not have vertical scroll. One inner div which should have vertical scroll and no horizontal scroll. Now Inner div should scroll  horizontal through scrolling of outer div as only outer div has horizontal scroll. Vertical scroll of inner div is specific to inner div only. No impact of vertical scroll of inner div on outer div.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8dmwLwfa/1/      created a fiddle. Here you can see outer Red div has horizontal scroll through which inner blue div is scrolling. Both Divs are scrolling with horizontal scroll of outer div. Problem is now with Vertical scroll of Inner div. I need vertical scroll in inner div.